# error TS2532 Angluar : object undefined in ngIf condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So in my Angular Project I have  two shared files called Posters.ts and the-Posters respectfully. I defined the class Posters in the first  and made a table in the-Posters.

Posters.ts

```
export class Posters {
    id? : string ; 
    url? : string;
    categories ? : string
    nsold? : Number;
    posterA? : boolean;
    constructor (args : Posters ={}) {
        this.id=args.id;
        this.url=args.url;
        this.categories = args.categories ;
        this.nsold = args.nsold;
        this.posterA=args.posterA;
    }
}
```

the-posters.ts

```
import { Posters } from "./posters";
export const POSTERS : Posters [] = [
{
    id : '1',
    url : '../../assets/Posters/manufacturing/p1.jpg',
    categories :"MANUFACTURING",
    nsold : 15,
    posterA : true
},
{
    id : '2',
    url : '../../assets/Posters/IT/p2.jpg',
    categories :"IT",
    nsold : 30,
    posterA : true
},
{
    id : '3',
    url : '../../assets/Posters/manufacturing/p3.jpg',
    categories :"MANUFACTURING",
    nsold : 35,
    posterA : true
}
]
```

and then I imported it in a component called home-user. and tried the information in home-user.component.html

home-user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { POSTERS } from '../../shared/models/the-posters';
import { Posters } from '../../shared/models/posters';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-user',
  templateUrl: './home-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-user.component.css']
})
export class HomeUserComponent implements OnInit {

  tabPosters : Posters [] = POSTERS;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  

}
```

home-user.component.html

```
<h1> Manufacturing</h1>
<div *ngFor="let p of tabPosters; let i = index">
    <span *ngIf="p.categories == 'MANUFACTURING' ">
    <span *ngIf="p.posterA === true " >
    <img src="{{p.url}}" alt="">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<h1> IT</h1>
<div *ngFor="let p of tabPosters; let i = index">
    <span *ngIf="p.categories == 'IT' ">
    <span *ngIf="p.posterA === true " >
    <img src="{{p.url}}" alt="">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<h1> Best Selling</h1>
<div *ngFor="let p of tabPosters; let i = index">
    <span *ngIf=" p.nsold >30 ">
    <span *ngIf="p.posterA === true " >
    <img src="{{p.url}}" alt="">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

and the Error is at **<span *ngIf=" p.nsold >30 ">** .according to Angular compiler p.nsold is undefined.

Comment: Are you getting runtime or compilt time error? Please reproduce the error using stackblitz to troubleshoot as code is correct. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try using the `non-null assertion operator ( ! )` and see if that resolves your issue:

```html
*ngIf="p?.nsold! > 30"
```

Comment: This one worked thanks ! :)